# Alternative Product image when page loads

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images, sort

OK this may sound like a very strange question but here I go.

Our inventory and product listings are managed outside of magento (Linnworks) to be exact.

Apparently there is no API connection for the sort order of the product images and therefore the main product image show randomly. this can be annoying when we have images of product parts and the image looks nothing like the actual product.

As a work around I was thinking that I could show an alternative image over the main image which will be the default product image? as the category page shows the defaul image fine.

Then on click of an alternative thumbnail image the first image(overlay) will dissapear and you will see the actual image the customer selects, if that makes sense.

Or is there another way to show the default image as it always changes when there is other images associated with the product

Help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: I think you should create new attribute, `Media Image` type

Comment: OK and do what with with?

Comment: Yes I will,  but can you explain this line: `I was thinking that I could show an alternative image over the main image which will be the default product image?`

Comment: So at the moment a random image will be the main image. I want to show the base image over the random image until they click a thumbnail image.

Comment: ok, can you select particular image as a "Base Image" by API ?

Comment: I have the option to select base image and when i set it, it gets sent across to magento but this images are still random

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39674/discussion-between-anil-suthar-and-mike-tim-turner).

Answer (score 0):

Its better you set one image as base image in Magento, and default magento api is capable to pull the details of base image. So you set base image as main image, no random listing anymore.

[image]

Comment: Base image is selected but I'm guessing Linnworks overrides it.